# How to show a multichannel spectrogram in Praat?

Tags: phonetics

I'd like to see a spectral representation of my left and right channels individually. I'm not sure which channel Praat's spectrogram corresponds to. How do I show multiple spectrograms, with each corresponding to a different channel?

Comment: Separate the channels, and display both channels w/ spectrogram. I assume you mean "in one edit window with 4 panels".

Comment: Yeah, it seems tedious to consistently split the track

Comment: maybe you can script the splitting and window showing.